# Array Parameter proplem

Tags: java

I'm stuck..... i have been trying to use Arrays in methods to count the number of numbers divisible by 10 from the range 1-100.
here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Journal5a {
// METHOD

public int[] creatArray (int size)
{
    int[] array = new int[size];
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] = r.nextInt(100);
    return array;
}

public  int[] DivByTen()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y[] = this.creatArray(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
        if (y[i] % 10 == 0)
        {
            x++;
        }

    return x;
}

public int[] printArray ()
{
    int[]   myArray = this.creatArray(1);
    for (int i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++)
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    return myArray;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Journal5a j5a = new Journal5a();
    j5a.DivByTen();
}
```

So my output would be :

```
there is 10 numbers divisible by 10
```

Another problem is the x used in the method DivByTen isn't being returned.

Comment: Why are you populating **arrays** *randomly* to solve your problem?

Comment: `DivByTen` returns an `int` while it is of type `int[]`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it's a problem from school..I''m new to programming. plus I'm trying to have a range from 1-100.

Answer (score 0):

Your createArray() method fills the array with random numbers from 0-99, so it is not clear how much numbers are dividable by 10.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 array[i] = i;
}
```

will create an array with values from 0 to size - 1.

The second problem is that your return type is int[] instead of int

Comment: I have modified that already and it still gives me a random number

Comment: you are giving 1 to your createArray method, so the size of your array is 1. pass 100 to get an array of size 100

Answer (score 0):

First, create and fill the array. For the range `1` to `100` you would need to pass in `100` and either start with `i` at `1` (or add `1` to `i` when you initialize the array);

```
private static int[] creatArray(int size) {
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Next, count the multiples of some `multiple`. Something like,

```
private static int countMultiples(int[] arr, int multiple) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int val : arr) {
        if (val != 0 && val % multiple == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Finally, call the above methods and output the result

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int multiple = 10;
    int count = countMultiples(creatArray(100), multiple);
    System.out.printf("There are %d numbers divisible by %d.", count, multiple);
}
```

Output is

```
There are 10 numbers divisible by 10.
```